# Scala: iterate over collection in random order without creating a copy

Tags: scala, random, collections, iteration, traversal

Is there a way in Scala to obtain a stream/view/iterator for an immutable collection (e.g. List or Vector) which will traverse the collection in random order? As far as I understand Random.shuffle(coll) creates a copy, and it is not a memory-efficient way. Is Random.shuffle(coll.view) (or coll.stream or coll.iterator) a better approach? Does this create a noticeable CPU overhead? Or is there some more appropriate way?

Comment: Seeking for (pseudo) random number generator where first myVector.size values are unique without having to shuffle an initial range, unfruitful search so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffling algorithms need to move randomly around in the collection and need to remember past choices somehow.  The immutable collections are not very speedy with random access (`O(n)` instead of `O(1)` for `List`, arguably `O(1)` for `Vector` but the constant factor is large).

Copying the collection, in comparison, is almost always the wise thing to do.

Comment: In (my) case when memory is more valuable than CPU copying is not acceptable. So I need the less CPU-intensive approach. Does Random.shuffle(myVector.iterator) copy the whole vector?

Comment: @Uniqus See line 108 in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L1 (new ArrayBuffer created)

Comment: @Uniqus - If you have enough entries for another set of pointers to be an issue, I'm pretty sure you won't want to go from a runtime of `O(n)` to traverse the randomized list to `O(n^2)`.  When `n` is big, `O(n^2)` is pretty awful (seconds -> weeks).

Comment: Yep, storing past choices will still eat memory (not at once, but with time), so it will just postpone a potential problem. So the only acceptable way is indeed to make a copy. Well, thanks to everyone, question is answered.

Comment: There is [a (possible) solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20194928/1410299) in C++, but I decided to stick with copying.

Comment: @Uniqus - Finding cycles that fit nicely within/near your sequence length is not a problem solved in general in that answer, and when you do solve it you get _one_ shuffle of the data.  If you want to shuffle your data differently, you need another.  So I wouldn't really consider that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If collections copying is taken into account, consider shuffling an `Array` of indices to a `Vector` of interest, for instance like this,

```
val myVector: Vector[MyObject] = ...

val shuffledIdx = util.Random.shuffle(0 until myVector.size)
```

This copies a sequence of `Int`, likely *lighter* than dedicated objects. Then

```
shuffledIdx.map { idx => task (myVector(idx)) }
```

iterates / maps over each item in `myVector` in a random order.